# Pyautogui Clicks in Wrong Position on MacBook

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am trying to make a program that clicks a color on the screen. However, it clicks in the complete wrong position. I set the region to be the exact same resolution as my screen. I even tried saving the screenshot and it looked exactly as expected.

I am on a MacBook, and someone tried running this on a windows PC, and it worked. So I think it might be some scaling issues with my MacBook.

Here is the code:

```py
import pyautogui
import time
from itertools import product

color = (163, 194, 229)

time.sleep(5)

s = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(0, 0, 2560, 1600))
print(s.width, s.height)
for x, y in product(range(s.width), range(s.height)):
    if s.getpixel((x, y))[:-1] == color:
        print(x,y)
        pyautogui.click(x, y)
        break
```

(I am excluding the last element in the getpixel tuple because, my MacBook for some reason takes a fourth element)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pixels are not the same as screen coordinates. If you have a [Retina display](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202471) (which many Apple screens after 2015 have), then every screen coordinate contains 4 pixels.

To get the correct position, divide the pixel coordinates by 2.

Comment: Where in the code are the pixel coordinates I should multiply by 2? I tried multiplying  a few values by 2, but none of if it worked. I am probably just multiplying the wrong thing.

Comment: @Emil I wrote wrong. `x` and `y` are in pixel coordinates and therefore twice as large as the screen coordinates. So you should divide by 2.

Comment: But also, you are not iterating through the whole screen, just one quarter.

Comment: How do I iterate through my whole screen?

Comment: @Emil You multiply by 2 on each axis. Going one step on the screen in the x-axis is going to step 2 pixels.

Comment: I tried multiplying height and width in the for loop by 2, and I got `IndexError: image index out of range`. I also tried printing each iteration of the for loop without multiplying by 2 and it did actually iterate through the whole screen. Also, I still don't understand where I am supposed to divide by 2.

Comment: @Emil First, remove the `region` keyword. You say you want the full screen anyway. Then add `pyautogui.click(x//2, y//2)`.